# Customer group specific order view in Magento Community Edition

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm working on creating a web shop for a friend and I'm using the Magento Community Edition. I've encountered a problem which I can't seem to find an answer for:

**I have three different customer groups and three different Admin roles. Is it possible to only show sales orders for customer group A to Admin Role A and hide all other orders from other customer groups for this specific admin in the back-end?**

Articles, tutorials or other resources is greatly appreciated!

Thanx in advance.

/IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with community out of the box.

You most certainly could write something to achieve what you want. This could be done properly or in a 'quick and dirty' fashion. The 'properly' way is with modules, over-rides and all kinds of stuff to make sure that admin A cannot open customer group B's orders under any circumstances whatsoever. The 'quick and dirty' approach would just not show those orders in the order grid.

Comment: Thanx for your response! I actually found this free plugin that does exactly what I want: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-orders-access-by-customer-group.html